# What is a sensible way to pipe the first argument and all proceeding arguments separately

Tags: command-line, xargs, cut

**Problem**

I have a command which I alias as a convenience where I annoyingly need to use `--` to specify some additional parameters after the call to the command.

Take the example below, the command is called `foo` and alias called `run`:

```
alias run=foo --bar --baz
```

`bar` and `baz` are arguments which are always there so they are in the alias. Now I want to call the command, it needs at least **one required argument** followed by the additional parameters which proceed the option ender `--`.

Concretely when I call `run` I call it like so:

```
run file1 -- option1 option2
```

This is valid, option 1 and 2 get passed along as expected.

**What I would like**

What I would possibly like to do is just have a single alias and run the following `run file1 option1 option2` and have the alias handle positioning the arguments before or after the `--` (which would be in the alias).

**Potential answers**

What I struggle with here is coming up with a solution that doesn't involve *too* much logic. Ideally I just want something like `xargs` to be gain access argument1 and then arguments1+... but this doesn't seem to be what it was made for.
I could also do something with `cut` (`cut -d' ' -p1` and `cut -d' ' -f2-` both work but that sort of string cutting may not be the nicest solution).

I'm all ears on an elegant solution here

Comment: From [6.6 Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) in the bash manual: "For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO it would be more sensible to use a shell function instead of an alias:

```
run() { 
  file="$1"
  shift
  foo --bar --baz "$file" -- "$@"
}
```

Comment: You're right, thats a lot more readable, thank you!